# Changing bootstrap nav a:active background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, nav

I am trying to change the background colour of Bootstrap nav links when a user click them.

At the moment once a link has been clicked it goes grey while the browser loads the next page, how do I remove this colour?

I have tried:

```
.navbar li a:active {
    background: rgb(115, 110, 95) !important;
}
```

No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
background-color:rgb(115,110,95);
}
```

Comment: Still happening, not sure what it is.

Comment: It's not the active class I am trying to change.

Comment: Then what class are you trying to change?  Post a jsfiddle please

Comment: add :visited to the answer Jake provided